# How to sign out of google account that is authenticated with Android studio firebase cloud testing

Tags: android-studio, firebase-test-lab

I am trying to use the AS cloud testing tab for running espresso tests on [FTL](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests#run). But realized that I authenticated with a wrong google account. 
[image]
How can I sign out of this account and login with a different google account.
I tried restarting AS with no use.

Is deleting the cache an option? Where is the cache for this located, I can try to manually delete a file.

Answer (score 0):

Found out there is a menu item in AS like this
[image]

Click on it would show an add account option and let's us login into a different account and sign out
[image]

After this **quit** android studio and reopen